# Combining address fields to one field

Tags: php

Hi I am currently using a 3rd party API that gets address data based on postcode and address lookup, it returns an array over xml, which is working fine.  Out of the 30+ available fields that are returned there are 8 I would like to insert into a memo box type field, there are

```
$item["Line1"] . "<br/>";
$item["Line2"] . "<br/>";
$item["Line3"] . "<br/>";
$item["Line4"] . "<br/>";
$item["Line5"] . "<br/>";
$item["PostTown"] . "<br/>";
$item["County"] . "<br/>";
$item["Postcode"] . "<br/>";
```

My question is, how would I go about putting these into a field and removing blank lines so that the address runs contiguous?

For example, using the above, if Line 3, Line 4 and Line 5 were null, the result would be

Line 1 
Post Town  
County  
PostCode

The only way I can think of is by writing a very long if statement, which I'd rather not have to do unless someone here can tell me a smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (untested):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if(!is_null($item['Line'.$i]) && strlen($item['Line'.$i])) {
        // do something with it
        echo $item['Line'.$i] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

If you want it for every field in `$item`:

```
foreach($item as $value) {
    if(!is_null($value) && strlen($value)) {
        // do something with it
        echo $value . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the 3 fields: "PostTown","County","Postcode"

Comment: @Naruto now it does... but we don't know whether OP wants to perform this on every item in the array...

Comment: He doesn't only on those 8 fields as mentioned in the question ;)

Comment: Yep... but he uses it as an example... Maybe @Simon79 could clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the keys into an array like:

```
$arrayKeys = array("Line1","Line2","Line3","Line4","Line5","PostTown","County","Postcode");
```

then you can just loop over it adding the output to another variable and echo it like:

```
$output = "";

foreach($arraysKeys as $key){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $item){
        $output .= $item[$key] . "<br/>";
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: You have an error there: "$key_exists" should be "array_key_exists".

Comment: Sorry, you are right. key_exists() indeed works fine.

Comment: In the comments of the php-reference of `key_exists()` it says this alias has been deprecated... To be safe, better use `array_key_exists()` -> http://php.net/key_exists

Comment: @RichardBernards thx for the tip, I will edit and keep it in mind in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an "if" statement, you could use [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
(strlen(trim($item["Line1"])) > 0 ? $item["Line1"] . "<br/>" : "");
(strlen(trim($item["Line2"])) > 0 ? $item["Line2"] . "<br/>" : "");
(strlen(trim($item["Line3"])) > 0 ? $item["Line3"] . "<br/>" : "");
(strlen(trim($item["Line4"])) > 0 ? $item["Line4"] . "<br/>" : "");
(strlen(trim($item["Line5"])) > 0 ? $item["Line5"] . "<br/>" : "");
(strlen(trim($item["PostTown"])) > 0 ? $item["PostTown"] . "<br/>" : "");
(strlen(trim($item["County"])) > 0 ? $item["County"] . "<br/>" : "");
(strlen(trim($item["Postcode"])) > 0 ? $item["Postcode"] . "<br/>" : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to make $item['line'] an array and the loop through this array?

$item["Line"][0]

$item["Line"][1]

...

```
foreach ($item['line'] as $line) {

if (!empty($line)) {$line . "<br/>";}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this:

```
array_walk($item, function($val) {
   if (!is_null($val)) echo $val. "<br/>";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with if condition as follows:

```
if(trim($item["Line1"])):echo $item["Line1"] . "<br/>";endif;
if(trim($item["Line2"])):echo $item["Line2"] . "<br/>";endif;
```

Another way:

```
foreach($item as $cur){
  if(trim($cur)): echo "$cur <br>"; endif;
}
```